# Why does my MaybeT (State <type>) () ignore state changes?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

**Short version:** when I use `runMaybeT` and then `runState` on a monad of type `MaybeT (State <type>) ()`, it looks like no state changes occur even though the `Maybe` result is equal to `Just ()`. Why?

**Full version:** I'm writing a program to solve the Towers of Hanoi. I represent the solution as a list of `State` monads that, when sequenced, manipulate an initial `Towers` state:

```
data Towers = Towers [Int] [Int] [Int]
    deriving (Show)
type Move = State Towers ()

towerMoves :: Int -> Rod -> Rod -> [Move]
towerMoves 1 r1 r2 = [pop r1 >>= push r2]
towerMoves n r1 r2 = topToTemp ++ (towerMoves 1 r1 r2) ++ topToFinal
  where
    r3 = other r1 r2
    topToTemp = towerMoves (n - 1) r1 r3
    topToFinal = towerMoves (n - 1) r3 r2

moves = towerMoves 5 First Third
initTowers = Towers [1,2,3,4,5] [] []

main = print $ snd $ runState (sequence_ moves) initTowers
```

Thus far, this program produces the correct output:

```
Towers [] [] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then, I wanted to verify that the program respected the rules of the puzzle, namely that no larger disc (represented by numbers here) comes before a smaller disc. I wanted to insert some kind of verification after every `Move`, so I tried to use the `MaybeT` monad transformer to send a failure down the list of moves:

```
verifiedMoves :: [MaybeT (State Towers) ()]
verifiedMoves = map ((>> verify) . return) moves
  where
    check :: [Int] -> Bool
    check [] = True
    check [_] = True
    check (x:y:ys) = (x < y) && check (y:ys)
    verify :: MaybeT (State Towers) ()
    verify = do
        (Towers xs ys zs) <- lift get
        guard (check xs && check ys && check zs)
```

Accordingly I changed the `main` monad:

```
main = maybe (putStrLn "violation") (const $ print finalTowers) v
  where
    (v, finalTowers) = runState (runMaybeT $ sequence_ verifiedMoves) initTowers
```

Now the output looks wrong, like no state changes occurred:

```
Towers [1,2,3,4,5] [] []
```

If I make the initial state invalid, it indeed fails the verification. So if there is no state change because the effects of the `Move`s got interrupted, I would expect the output to be the word "violation."

**Why**, after applying `runMaybeT`, is the result of applying `runState` equal to `(Just (), Towers [1,2,3,4,5] [] [])`?

---

Here is the rest of the code, for reference. I tried [lifting the `get` and `put` monads in my `pop` and `push` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973351/monad-transformers-implementation-of-a-stack-machine-with-maybet-state-stack), but that produced the same output.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Rod = First | Second | Third
    deriving (Show)

other :: Rod -> Rod -> Rod
other First Second = Third
other Second First = Third
other First Third = Second
other Third First = Second
other Second Third = First
other Third Second = First

getRod :: Towers -> Rod -> [Int]
getRod (Towers x y z) First  = x
getRod (Towers x y z) Second = y
getRod (Towers x y z) Third  = z

setRod :: Rod -> Towers -> [Int] -> Towers
setRod First t ds  = Towers ds r2 r3
  where
    r2 = t `getRod` Second
    r3 = t `getRod` Third
setRod Second t ds = Towers r1 ds r3
  where
    r1 = t `getRod` First
    r3 = t `getRod` Third
setRod Third t ds  = Towers r1 r2 ds 
  where
    r1 = t `getRod` First
    r2 = t `getRod` Second

pop :: Rod -> State Towers Int
pop r = do
    t <- get
    let ds = t `getRod` r
        d = head ds
        load = setRod r
    put $ t `load` (tail ds)
    return d

push :: Rod -> Int -> State Towers ()
push r d = do
    t <- get
    let ds = t `getRod` r
        load = setRod r
    put $ t `load` (d:ds)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this line

```
verifiedMoves = map ((>> verify) . return) moves
```

equivalent to

```
= map (\m -> return m >> verify) moves
```

but for all `x`, we have `return x >> a = a`, thus

```
= map (\_ -> verify) moves
```

So you discarded the moves. You probably meant to use `lift` instead of `return` there.

Comment: That fixed it and enlightened me. Thank you.